# SQL list users from table one and count / compare in the other table where value is NULL

Tags: sql

I have a table 'users':

```
id | name
1    Jane
2    David
3    Olivia
```

The other table 'general' :

```
ida | iduser | discription | motivation
1       2      bla bla       Because we need it
2       3      bla again     NULL
3       3      test          We do not have this yet
4       2      another item  certainly necessary
...
```

The result I want to achive is a list of the users from table 'users' and look up in the other table 'general' that for user 2 there is no result NULL in the column motivation so the end result for user 2 is 'TRUE' and for user 3 there is a result with NULL so the end result for this is 'FALSE'.

So I want to have a result that loop out something like this:

```
name | motivation
Jane   TRUE
David  TRUE
Olivia FALSE
....
```

How can I achieve the result?

Comment: which database engin are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by Gordon (+1) might be the most efficient, but we can also try aggregating on the `general` table and joining to that:

```
SELECT
    u.name,
    CASE WHEN t.iduser IS NULL THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS motivation
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT iduser
    FROM general
    GROUP BY iduser
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN motivation IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
) t
    ON u.id = t.iduser;
```

### Demo

Comment: @WFender You should accept one of these answers.  I would probably go with Gordon's answer.

Comment: Thx. The only thing (unfortunately) working for my is you answer. I've tried this also in a SQL server and use php/html to output which also works. unfortunately the sql of 'avb' doesn't. Is there anything I need to adapt to have a stable query for sql server?

Comment: Can you give me more background about what is not working?  My code certainly works on SQL Server in the demo I setup.  Is there some issue with your data?

Comment: Your SQL works fine! So there is no issue with that. I just asked the question if it will stay working on my mysql server. but didn't see your demo was on mysql 5.6 :-) thx!

Comment: Aha!  I guessed the right database.  Actually, my query should run on pretty much any SQL database, so I don't think your concern was a real problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `not exists`:

```
select u.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from general g
                          where g.iduser = u.id and g.motivation is null
                         )
             then 0 else 1
        end) as demotivated_flag
from u;
```

Answer (score 0):

for sql server:

```
select u.*, ISNULL(c.truefalse, 'true') motivation
from users u
    outer apply (
        select top 1 'false' truefalse
        from general g
        where g.id = u.id
            and g.motivation is null
    ) c
```